# Cannot disable sleep on lid closing

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, power, power-management

New Mac user here. Got hold of two 2012 MacBook Pro notebooks. One of them has no battery and the other one has a slightly degraded battery. So here we're talking about the latter.

On this one with the degraded battery, I cannot find a way to prevent the Mac from sleeping if I close the lid. At max, I have deselected the checkbox that says *Put hard disks to sleep when possible*. So what I am looking for is a box that specifically says that closing the lid shouldn't put it to sleep (like in Windows).

Is there a way to achieve this on the OSX Catalina?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### I've found a solution which works most of the time for me.

> [**Amphetamine**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704) prevents my Mac from sleeping when I close the lid, even on battery.

Sometimes it still sleeps when lid is closed but this is rare.
I can live with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question/answer to this topic:  [How exactly could these commands to use MacBook in Clamshell Mode without a Power Adapter be dangerous? And how to revert them eventually?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/453683/119271)

> So what I am looking for is a box that specifically says that closing the lid shouldn't put it to sleep (like in Windows)

You are using this MacBook Pro in "closed clamshell mode."  Apple has, by default configured this mode to [require a power adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296299/119271).

In first link, it describes how to use `pmset` to disable hibernation and sleep-on-lid close.  I don't recommend doing this as it puts your data/machine state at risk because if you disable hibernation then there is no chance of saving that RAM state (sleep image) to disk.  Anything in RAM will be lost forever.