# How to ignore the magnet that turns off the MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, monterey

The MacBook 2015 has a magnet in it that detects when the lid closes and puts it to sleep.

I often walk around with both my MacBook and bluetooth speaker in hand these days, and often inadvertently the magnet in the speaker triggers the MacBook to sleep.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Are you walking around with your Mac like an open pizza  box?

Comment: @Allan yeah, I even sometimes use it to carry sandwiches and stuff when my hands are full

Comment: I’m having PTSD flashbacks from my time in Edu.  I can honestly say that this gives the sys/net admins heart palpitations when seeing this. I’s probably a good thing that your Mac goes to sleep because it writes anything in memory to the drive.  If you happen to drop it and power gets interrupted, you’ll save your “pending” data,  With it open, anything in memory can be lost.

Comment: See if this meets your needs:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/453683/119271