# Can't use external display while MacBook is closed without charging

Tags: battery, charging

I'm using MacBook Air with one of the Type-C port connected to a hub (connected to monitor and keyboard), another one connected to charger, when I want to connect with an hard disk (Type-C), I unplug the charger.

However the external monitor didn't work once I unplug the charger.  Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's how clamshell mode is supposed to work.  If you want to do this, you need to use an external hub that provides for charging.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Terminal Commands

Know the hibernate duration:

```
pmset -g I grep hibernatemode
```

Stop hibernate:

```
sudo pmset -a sleep 0
sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 0
sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1
```

**Note:**

Apple recommends not changing the hibernate mode using the `pmset` command. However, these commands will disable your laptop's sleep on lid-close trigger, so they should also solve the problem of being unable to use your laptop in clamshell mode without the power adapter. That said, use them at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t connect your monitor through the hub.  Go from one of the two Thunderbolt Type-C ports to your monitor.  This way, any changes made to the hub will have no effect on the monitor. I also advise you to get a USB-C hub with charging support (pass through) to better serve your needs.

While in closed clamshell mode, you must maintain power.  This is by design: [Why is it required to have your MacBook Pro plugged-in in closed-clamshell mode with an external display attached?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/296293/119271)

I am assuming you have either a 2020 Intel or M1 MacBook Air as it was the only models with Type-C ports.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with "any changes made to the hub will have no effect on the monitor", what kind of changes will be made to the hub in this case? So in my case, using a USB-C with charging support will solve it?

Comment: When using a hub, especially bus powered, with high current draw peripherals (drives, monitors, etc.) (un)plugging devices can affect other attached devices when the current draw spikes on these changes.